# Merge Dex Issue With Android Studio

Tags: java, android, emulation

My App is not bringing up an error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

This is y build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.monmos"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

//noinspection GradleCompatible
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-         core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'


//Fixed Crash FButton
implementation ('com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1')

//Libraries
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post the errors log and the code

Comment: why you do that ?? `just copy and paste` very bad very bad :(

Comment: The error seems to be in my gradle and in my classes that is why I put my github profile, so you can assess all the code.

Comment: 'UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5'
Check your attributes of 'FButton' in your xml. The color value is not as it should be : )

Comment: Ive added the color value of the button can you please look at it for me? Ive tried everything and the application is not runnning still, cant move forward with it.

Comment: Check the value of this: '@color/btsSignUp'

Comment: Still Not worked, if someone could please check my GITHUB profile and check the error, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Each one of your support libraries must use `26.+` (all the same version). You can't mix 27 and different 26 versions

Comment: Also, you put constraint layout and appcompat-v7 twice, so go over the dependencies and remove those you don't really need. For example, you don't need Glide and Picasso, and you don't need **all** the play services `:play-services:11.8.0`

Comment: Thanks mate successfull build however not running on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Is having conflicts with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
```

You can't have 2 versions of the same library. Either use one or the other.

Or you can add in your module's Build.Gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
...
}
```

It should solve the problem.

Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: And yes, please make sure your question looks nice on the preview before hitting that "post" button.